# How to create a WSO2 ESB Composite Application through the Integration Cloud API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-cloud

I want to create a ESB composite application (.car) through the API but this format is not listed in the supported types in the documentation [1]. Is it not possible to create car apps through the API or am I missing something here?

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationCloud/Integration+Cloud+APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this done by using the following command. I had to use **wso2esb** as the appTypeName and **24** as the runtime to create a ESB Composite Application through the API.

```
curl -v -b cookies -X POST https://integration.cloud.wso2.com/appmgt/site/blocks/application/application.jag -F action=createApplication -F applicationName=CloudIntegration -F applicationDescription=CloudIntegration -F appTypeName=wso2esb -F applicationRevision=1.0.0 -F uploadedFileName=WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car -F runtimeProperties=[] -F tags=[] -F fileupload=@/Users/dinuksha/Downloads/WSO2QuickStartGuideCapp_1.0.0.car -F isFileAttached=true -F conSpec=5 -F isNewVersion=false -F appCreationMethod=default -F setDefaultVersion=true -F runtime=24
```